# subset dataframe by removing duplicates for each level of a factor

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
df<- data.frame(region= c("1", "1", "1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2"),
            plot=c("1", "1", "1","2","2","2", "3","3","3","3"),
            interact=c("A_B", "C_D","C_D", "E_F","C_D","C_D", "D_E", 
            "D_E","C_B","A_B"))
```

And I would like to get count of all unique levels of `interact` for each plot subset. The final data frame would look like:

```
 result<- 
     Plot    freq
      1      2
      2      2
      3      3
```

I would like to use dplyr and have gotten this far:

```
 df2 <-df %>% group_by(plot) %>%mutate(freq=length(unique((interact))))
```

But with the code above I have yet to figure out a way where only one value per plot is represented (ie. duplicate values in `freq` for each unique  plot are removed).

Comment: You need a `summarize` instead of `mutate`: `df %>% group_by(plot) %>%summarise(freq = n_distinct(interact))`.

Comment: In base R, you could do `aggregate(interact ~ plot, data = df, function(x) length(unique(x)))` for a data.frame or `rowSums(table(df$plot, df$interact) > 0)` for a named vector.

Answer (score 2):

Try this .

```
df%>%group_by(plot)%>%summarise(n=length(unique(interact)))

    plot     n
1      1     2
2      2     2
3      3     3
```

or base on your own way.

```
df2 <-df %>% group_by(plot) %>%mutate(freq=length(unique((interact))))
df2=df2[!duplicated(df2$plot),]

  region   plot interact  freq
  <fctr> <fctr>   <fctr> <int>
1      1      1      A_B     2
2      1      2      E_F     2
3      1      3      D_E     3
```